# Node.js: How do I $pull from an array of $oid in Mongo/Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to remove an object from an array of $oid from within a single document with mongoose using `update`.

Here is a hypothetical schema based on the schema I'm using now:

```
var TestSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  otherRefs: [ {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'OtherSchema' } ]
});
```

An example document would look like (note: these aren't actual ObjectIDs from my db - I just randomly typed them in to give an idea of what the document would look like - the documents in my actual db have valid $oid values:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "56da0b6326008d0c24a4f029" },
  "name" : "name1",
  "otherRefs" : [
      {"$oid" : "56c340259402505c2720541b"},
      {"$oid" : "56c340259402505c2720541e"},
      {"$oid" : "56c340259402505c2720541f"},
      {"$oid" : "56d758862494c411001ca603"}
  ]
}
```

Here is the query I'm trying to use:

```
TestSchema.update(
    { '_id': testResult._id },
    { $pull: { 'otherRefs': { $oid : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId( refResult._id ) } } },
    false,
    true,
    function(err, success) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            res.json('success', success);
        }
    }
)
```

Have also tried `{ $pull: { 'otherRefs': refResult._id } }` with no success.

`testResult._id` and `refResult._id` are received from previous queries.

Been at this for a while now and can't seem to wrap my head around this problem. Hoping someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Now using:

```
TestSchema.update(
    { '_id': testResult._id },
    { $pull: { 'otherRefs': refResult._id ) } },
    function(err, success) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Success');
        }
    }
)
```

The query doesn't hang anymore and "Success" is getting logged but nothing is changed in the actual document in DB.

Comment: You don't need the `$oid` or the casting. Mongoose handles both for you `{ "$pull": { "otherRefs": refResult._id } }`. You also don't need the `upsert` or `multi` values ( nor do I think that's valid in this API ). You just doing one document so: `TestSchema.update({ "_id": testResult._id },{ "$pull": { "otherRefs": refResult._id } },function(err,numAffected) { });`

Comment: I've tried that but the query just hangs.

Comment: Well you included invalid options as well. Read the correct signature.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I took out the ``upsert`` and ``multi`` and the query no longer hangs and is going to the success condition but the Object isn't being pulled from the array in DB

Comment: Those are not valid `ObjectId` values. Where has this data come from?

Comment: The data is coming from previous queries. I.e: ``OtherSchema.findOne( { id : input }, function (err, refResult){ };`` Also, the example document I posted up is just random numbers - not an actual document in my collection - the actual documents have valid $oid values populated by Mongo.

Comment: We can read, so you already said from previous queries. What I am asking is "what wrote this data?" The reason everthing is failing is because things like `refResult._id` are actually a full object as `{ "$oid": "35u4ih3uh435iu344uh5i3" }`, and that is **not** and [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). So schema type conversions will be actually producing silent errors and the queries will not be issuing at all. Some other program is writing this data.

Comment: The values actually look like they might have come from a `meteor` application, and then exported with the `$oid` keys deliberately. That source then appears to have been incorrectly imported into the database you are using.

Comment: The data is being created and saved in another function. ``new OtherSchema( /*inputs*/ ).save ( function (err, otherRef { /* TestSchema query then*/ TestSchema.otherRefs.push(otherRef) } );``  The values aren't the actual values in the DB - i just typed them randomly, nothing was imported.

Comment: You don't seem to be understanding. You have `{ "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId }` set in your schema. These values are **not** `ObjectId` compliant. Validation and casting fails and nothing works. You need to fix the data.

Comment: You're right, I'm not sure I am understanding what you mean by ``not ObjectId complliant`` because validation and casting of the actual values in my db seem to be working elsewhere? Can you explain what you mean by fix the data?